# FTP connexion with implicit TLS by Python

Tags: python, ftp, tls1.2

Does anyone know how to connect FTP with implicit TLS via Python?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use this:  `from ftplib import FTP_TLS`
 [Refer to this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html)

Comment: This is explicit TLS, i.e. connect in plain on port 21 and upgrade to TLS. Implicit TLS means to start with the TLS handshake.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already seen that and I couldn't find a solution. The problem is that I use a network with a proxy limitation. When I want to use FTP I usually use FileZilla with connexion FTP with implicit TLS configuration and it works. What I want to do now is to translate what I am doing in FileZilla to Python.